# Add another class to a div

Tags: javascript

I have a function that checks the age of a form submission and then returns new content in a div depending on their age. Right now I am just using getElementById to replace the HTML content. BUt I think would work better for me if I could also add a class to a div as well. So for example I have.

```
if (under certain age) {
    document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = "<p>Good Bye</p>"; 
    createCookie('age','not13',0)
    return false;
} else {
    document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = "<p>Hello</p>";  
    return true;
}
```

What I would like to do is have everything in a div and if return false then that div disappears and is replaced with other content. Can I get any ideas on a good way to achieve this with pure JavaScript. I don't want to use jQuery for this particular function.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If the element has no class, give it one. Otherwise, append a space followed by the new className:

```
  var el = document.getElementById('hello');
  if(el) {
    el.className += el.className ? ' someClass' : 'someClass';
  }
```

Comment: awesome, thanks!  Can you please explain a bit more this part.. ' someClass' : 'someClass' 

why is it defined twice like that... what does the first part do?

Comment: @zac - that's the conditional operator. If `el.className` evaluates to true, the first value (after the question mark) gets assigned, if false then the second one gets assigned. It's an if..else shortcut. Take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: That `condition ? 'if true' : 'if false'; ` annotation is called a ternary operation. It works for multiple true/false trees, although they can get confusing beyond the first two.
`console.log(shift[i].status != 'active' ? shift[i].id : shift[i].hbn + shift[i].type == 'product' ? '-' + shift[i].id : ''`
It doesn't matter if your second condition is in the true block or the false block. It's just easier to read if it's in the false. If you have additional conditions in both sides, it's better to use multiple if-else-if blocks.

Comment: Is `+=` correct here? That'll *append* the old class name to the class name, so you'll end up duplicating the content. Don't you want a plain assignment here?

Comment: @DavidGiven Since that's a ternary operator, he's not actually outputting `el.className`, but using the ternary operator check for its existence. The conditional isn't output, but the true/false result is, depending on the existence of `className`.

Comment: Seven years have passed since this answer was published, while at the time this was the best way to do it, @Rich answer is a newer and a more concise method for dealing with CSS class names these days.

Answer (score 61):

Use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```
document.getElementById('hello').classList.add('someClass');
```

The `.add` method will only add the class if it doesn't already exist on the element. So no need to worry about duplicate class names.

Comment: This is by far the better way to do it. If the class already exists it's just added/removed (add/remove) vs. potentially adding the same class multiple times.

Answer (score 24):

You can append a class to the `className` member, with a leading space.

```
document.getElementById('hello').className += ' new-class';
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.className

Answer (score 4):

Well you just need to use `document.getElementById('hello').setAttribute('class', 'someclass');`.

Also `innerHTML` can lead to unexpected results! Consider the following;

```
var myParag = document.createElement('p');

if(under certain age)
{
    myParag.text="Good Bye";
    createCookie('age', 'not13', 0);
    return false;
{
else
{
    myParag.text="Hello";
    return true;
}

document.getElementById('hello').appendChild(myParag);
```

Comment: document.getElementById('hello').setAttribute('class', 'someclass')  does it too...

Answer (score 0):

In the DOM, the class of an element is just each class separated by a space. You would just need to implement the parsing logic to insert / remove the classes as necesary.

I wonder though... why wouldn't you want to use jQuery? It makes this kind of problem trivially easy.

Answer (score 0):

I use below function to animate UiKit gear icon using Just JavaScript

```js
document.getElementById("spin_it").onmouseover=function(e){
var el = document.getElementById("spin_it");
var Classes = el.className;
var NewClass = Classes+" uk-icon-spin";
el.className = NewClass;
console.log(e);
}
```

```html
<span class="uk-icon uk-icon-small uk-icon-gear" id="spin_it"></span>
```

This code not work here...you must add [UIKit](http://getuikit.com/) Style to it

Answer (score -1):

I am facing the same issue. If parent element is hidden then after showing the element chosen drop down are not showing.
This is not a perfect solution but it solved my issue. After showing the element you can use following code.

```
function onshowelement() { $('.chosen').chosen('destroy'); $(".chosen").chosen({ width: '100%' }); }
```