# Highlight a thumbnail when it is clicked in gallery.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have made a gallery.php. The code is as follows:

```
<div id="galleryImage">    
    <ul>    
        <li>
            <a href= "gallery.php?imgName='artistvan'">
            <img src="thumbnail/artistvan.jpg" title="The artist van" alt="The artist van"/></a>
        </li>
        ....
        ....
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have kept 25 li tag for 25 images.

The thumnails are on the right hand side of the div tag. When a thumbnail is clicked, the related image appears. I am passing imgName as parameter. So, it retrieves the related image from MySQL.

My question is, when I click thumbnail, that thumbnail should change so it can be figure out which link has been clicked. At the moment when I click, it retrieves an image but then there is no difference between clicked image and unclicked images.

I've tried a lot with CSS and somewhat javascript but I couldn't figure out. I would appreciate for your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How exactly do you want it to change? You need to be a bit more specific and also offer some examples of what you have tried.

Comment: If you want this to remain on the same page, javascript (read AJAX) will be the way to go. You could accomplish this using a form and page load (pure PHP/HTML), but that would be a bit clunky in my opinion.

Comment: In gallery.php page, I have made <div> with 25 <li> tags, in order to show 25 thumbnails. These thumbnailes are in between  <a href...></a> tag. What I want, when I click a thumbnail, that image should change to see the difference between clicked and not clicked thumbnails. If this is not understandable then I would again type the code and try to make it understandable. please let me know..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some class for indicating clicked thumbnail with jQuery:

```
$('.myThumbnail').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('clickedThumbnailClass');
    /* rest of code */
})
```

Comment: I haven't used jquery before. I have used javascript but not much. So javascript would be comfortable at the moment. Can I get help for that please

Comment: @Toie i suggest you to use jQuery (save kids in Africa :D ). To add class in js: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739667/add-another-class-to-a-div-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could try [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). In any case you don't want to use jQuery take a look over here to [add and remove a class without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787383/what-is-the-solution-to-remove-add-a-class-in-pure-javascript)

```
$('#galleryImage img').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5SBQ/)**

Answer (score 0):

Not much different then the others but to prevent the other images from having the same effect you should include this extra line.

**`$('ul li')`, make sure to change `ul li` to what ever selector your images will be.**

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul li').on('click', function() {
       $('ul li').removeClass('active'); // removes the active class form the other images
       $(this).addClass('active'); 
    });
});
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q8Mv4/2/)

---

To set up your website to use jQuery follow these steps,

Make sure to add this to your `<head>` tag to link to the jQuery library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Next you can add a the script into a script tag or on its own .js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   /* Script goes here */
</script>
```

The script tag can go at the end or beginning of your html doc.

Comment: Hi, This is the first time I am trying to use JS. I've seen DEMO from your link. I would like to first experiment with the same code on my localhost. I have pasted the code in Dreamweaver. Would you be kind to tell me to insert JS code what shoud I Use. <style> tag or I don't know. Please let me know..

Comment: You should use a script tag or a separate .js file to save it on. I will add some more info to my answer on how to use jQuery.

Comment: I am sorry to ask you again. What I've done as you've mentioned, I've put src="http:..." and 2nd <script="text/java...> in the head tag. and then HTML, CSS from the above link Demo. but there is no difference when I click to an image. Would you please let me know where I am making mistake.

Comment: Can you provide me a link to the site?

Comment: OK. I have it on my localhosst but I put it on Web hosting now and post a link to it. Is this ok?

Comment: http://kmd-r.dmu.ac.uk. Here, click on 'Crimean War Photos' tab  and let me know please.

Comment: After looking through your website source files I don't see you linking to jQuery in the head tag and also don't find your script anywhere. Refer to this link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hawJc

Comment: Dear Josh, Can you look at the website, I have put on hosting service please. vyomweb.com/RogerFenton  I have applied JS but it applys for a second and ran back. I am very thankful for your help.