# How to add same css class to all custom elements in polymer.

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polyfills

I have tried

```
<template>
        <link rel="import" href="ele-css.html">
      ......
<template>
```

also tried to add css in parent element and inherit that element.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? Are you trying to add a css class to all instances of the element, all elements in its shadow dom...?

Comment: all elements in its shadow dom.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a class to all elements in an element's shadow dom is no different than adding a class to all elements in the document. The difference is what DOM tree you're working in :)

In `ready()`, you could use `this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll` to query the element' shadow tree:

```
ready: function() {
  var els = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('*');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el, i) {
    el.classList.add('someClass');
  });
}
```

My next question is why do you want to do this? If it's for styling, a class on the element itself would be much nice and more performant. You could then use that as a styling hook to style elements in the shadow dom.

```
:host(.someClass) * {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Fwiw, in Polymer, you can do `els.array().forEach...`

Comment: sorry but i want to know that if i have 10 diff. custom element and i want to apply same css to all of 10 diff. custom element for example font colour than what ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing it in pure JS? http://jsfiddle.net/a9V8N/

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('myelement');

for(var i = 0 ; i < elems.length ; i ++){
    elems[i].className += elems[i].className ? ' someClass' : 'someClass';
}
```

Adding a class in js: [Add another class to a div with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739667/add-another-class-to-a-div-with-javascript)

Comment: Why not use `elems[i].classList.add('someClass')`?

Comment: you can not give class to custom element's shadow dom as you given above. For example i want to give class to my div inside template of custom element.

Comment: `this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('myelement').array().forEach(function(e) { e.classList.add('someClass'); })` ... although there is almost certainly a better way to achieve whatever effect you are after. [Note: `array()` function comes with Polymer, if you are not using Polymer, you can use the for loop as above].