# Arrange divs dynamically like in the picture

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to arrange in a container first at all 3 divs.
Depending which size has the browser has, show keep the div=leftCol and the div midCol the same position inline and the div=rightCol should be arrange automatically after the div=leftCol.

The div=midCol should be in this case re-sizable vertically.

The footer should show after the div=container

How do should do this? Im getting confuse.

Here is the HTML Code.

```
> <div id="container">
 <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="leftCol">
    </div>  

    <div id="midCol"
    </div>

    <div id="rightCol"
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
            <!--FOOTER -->
    <div id="footer"> 
    <h1> NEWS © All Rights Reserved</h1>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS Code.

```
<style type="text/css"> 
html {
    height: 100%;   
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    height: 100%;   
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    #container {
        width:40%;
        min-height:600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color:#424040;
    }



    #leftCol {
        width: 120px;
        background-color: #FFC600;
        min-height: 250px;
        float: left;
        display:inline;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    #midCol {
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #C0FF00;
        min-height: 250px;
        float: left;
        display:inline;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    #rightCol {
        width: 120px;
        background-color: #FF0057;
        min-height: 250px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;  
    }



    #footer {
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #E0065A;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

What is wrong with this code?
Why the footer doesnt appear at the end of the container?
How to arrange the leftCol, midCol and the rightCol inside the container div?

When the browser will be re-size... how to arrange the rightCol below the leftCol?
And last how to re-size the midCol so that will be always the high as the news.htm?

You can take a look into the picture I made.
http://postimg.org/image/l8enq2x27/

BTW the div in the middle should have a swipe vertical event.

THNX VERY MUCH FOR YOUR SUPPORT !!! ³

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MbSGs/)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="leftCol"></div>
        <div id="midCol"></div>
        <div id="rightCol" </div></div>
    </div>
    <!--FOOTER -->
    <div id="footer">
         <h1> NEWS © All Rights Reserved</h1>

    </div>
```

I hope your looking for this.But if you want to obtain the complete result you have to write media queries on the mid block on which size you want it to be 100% and its better using bootstrap.

Comment: Hello Danny, Thnx a bunch. I thought that I dont need the wrapper. I put ones, but didnt work. So I deleted it.

Your suggestion about media queries and bootstraps are a whole new level for me.
Let me give a try.

I really appreciate your help.
Cheers!

Comment: Danny just a question. How can i put the footer at the bottom of the container? The footer should be at the very bottom ALWAYS.

Comment: If you always want your footer to appear at the bottom use #footer{position:fixed;bottom:0px;right:0px;left:0px;}. If you want it at the bottom of the container, use #footer{position:absolute; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px;}.

I would suggest, however - if possible - to create a footer using the footer html tag <footer></footer> instead of creating one using the div id as you have. This way it will always show up after your body elements (unless you give it position properties that make it do otherwise)

Comment: Hi Danny, Once again THNX A BUNCH. I tried to see what happens thefirst one: #footer{position:fixed;bottom:0px;right:0px;left:0px;} I use these once, but these will positioned at the end of the page. The other: #footer{position:absolute; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px;} will not be positioned at the bottom of the container :( ... Today I saw a tutorial about html tag exactly how you wrote, but I didnt understood, because wasnt explain. Now with your help I get it. I will tried that. THUMBS UP! BTW.. Im a graphic guy. I own you one. If you need some graphic just let meknow

Comment: DAMN! I check my earlier code and was missing this ">" to close the divs. Now I know why didnt work at the biggining Ò.Ó I hate taht.

Comment: Yea i saw that first only combo. And i have rectified that in my fiddle...... All make that mistake. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **css media queries**, this may be what you want (google it for more info)

Here is a link that provides some information: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Another option would be to create a js onresize function that would add and remove classes dynamically:

- **resize** *javascript* link (`onresize`): http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp
- **resize** *jquery* link (`resize()`): http://api.jquery.com/resize/
- **add class** *javascript* link (`.className`):
  [Add another class to a div with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739667/add-another-class-to-a-div-with-javascript)
- **add class** *jquery* link (`addClass()`):
  http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Where the class you add would exist in your css file

Comment: Hello ctwheels,
I thank you also a bunch.
Definitely I will take a look on the css media queries and bootstraps like Danny posted.



Guys!! Truly appreciate your infos. That help me an defenitely I look further on this new solutions that I didnt touch jet.

Cheers!!

Comment: Here is simple example using media queries: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/8Wu9a/2/

Comment: Awesome!³ BIG BIG THNX ³ I need to study how it works.
I own you one. If you need some grapics you ask me. Im a graphic designer ;)

Comment: Glad to help, if you have any other questions, feel free to ask them!