# Dynamically add class based on page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navagation list written with bootstrap css:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class=""><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                </ul>
```

My question is how can I use javascript to add the class "active" to the "li" tags using javascript? I want it to have the active class on index.html for home and the same for about.html

Is this possible?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060467/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Active Navigation Class Based on URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060467/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JavaScript

```
var siteList = document.URL.split("/");
var site = siteList[siteList.length - 1];
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
    var item = list[index];
    var link = item.firstElementChild;
    var href = link ? String(link.href) : "-";
    if (href.replace(".html","") === site) {
        item.classList.add("open");
    } else {
        item.classList.remove("open");
    }
}
```

### Explanation

You can get the current `URL` using `document.URL`, you probably want the just the last part, so you'll have to split it and get the last part, which in your case will be `index`, `about` etc.

Then get all the `li` elements and iterate through them.
If they don't have an `a` child then ignore it.
If they do get the `href` attribute and remove the `.html` at the end.
If that text is the same as the `site variable`, then that means you should open the element, otherwise close it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clean, and there's probably a better way to do it, but:

HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li id="navIndex" class=""><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li id="navAbout" class=""><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS (somewhere)

```
// Map ids with html page names
var pages = { 
    navIndex: "index.html",
    navAbout: "about.html"
};

// Iterate over map
for(var property in pages) {

    // Check to make sure that the property we're iterating on is one we defined
    if(pages.hasOwnProperty(property)) {

        // indexOf will be 0+ if it appears in the string
        if(window.location.href.indexOf(pages[i]) > -1) {

            // we can use property because we defined the map to be same as ids
            // From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739667/add-another-class-to-a-div-with-javascript
            var el = document.getElementById(property);
            el.className += el.className ? ' active' : 'active';
            break; // no need to keep iterating, we're done!
        }
    } 
}
```

This is more or less a "dirty" approach because it requires more than just JavaScript to get to work ([see Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44010947/1985574) for a cleaner implementation).

First we set identifiers on our `<li>` elements, then we map out those identifiers with their respective href attributes.

Once we have the `<li>`s mapped out, we then iterate over the map's keys (which we set to be the `id` attributes on our `<li>`s) and check if the `href` attribute is present within the site's `window.location.href`, if it is: add the `active` class and stop searching, otherwise we keep on trucking.